# How Can I create a function in Haskell which calculates the number of times I call "fib" function?

Tags: haskell, fibonacci

I have created a function in Haskell which is called "fib", which obviously calculates the fibonacci number:

```
fib :: Integer -> Integer
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x
    | x < 0 = error "argumento negativo"
    | otherwise = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)
```

But now, I would like to do a function called "callsFib", which has to calculate the number of times that it calls "fib" function in order to calculate its fibonacci number. For exaple:

callsFib (3) = 5, because fib (3) = fib(2) + fib(1) = fib (1) + fib (0) + fib (0)

Comment: callsFib (3)  should be 4. fib (3) = fib(2) + fib(1) , fib(2)  = fib (1) + fib (0) so only 4 calls

Answer (score 2):

It will look like this:

```
callsFib :: Integer -> Integer
callsFib 0 = 0
callsFib 1 = 0
callsFib x
    | x < 0 = error "argumento negativo"
    | otherwise = 2 + callsFib (x - 1) + callsFib (x - 2)
```

Comment: i think it would not work, because you are adding 2 and a fib number

Comment: You can try it and see if result is ok.

Comment: i have just tried it, and it doesnt work

Comment: How exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: i mean it doesnt get the correct solutions, the code is not correct like that

Comment: @talex Well, it gives the wrong answer for 0. And 1.  And 2, and..  probably every input. The structure is right, but the base cases are wrong (if you call `fib 0`, you definitely called `fib` more than 0 times) and the recursive case is wrong (if you call `fib 2`, how many calls to `fib` does it make more than the number of calls to `fib 1` and `fib 0`?).

Comment: What answer you expect for 0? If you expect 1 then my solution is off by 1. I only count calls from `fib` itself.